# Energy of the photon emitted when an atom in an excited state goes to its ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

I was trying to solve the following problem and I realised that there are some things I do not understand:

> An atom with only one electron and mass $M$ is at rest. Its electron is in an excited state with energy $E_i$. At some point, is goes to its ground state, whose energy is $E_f$, emitting a photon that moves in the $x$ direction. Does the atom stay at rest? If it does not, find the expression of the recoil speed as a function  of $M$ and $\Delta E$.

I think that the atom must experience some recoil, because the photon it emits has some momentum and the total momentum of the system should be conserved. Moreover, energy should be conserved as well. When I write the conservation of the energy and the linear momentum I get:
$$
p_\gamma + p_{at} = 0
$$
becuase the atom is originally at rest, and
$$
E_i = E_f + E_\gamma + K
$$
where $K$ is the kinetic energy gained by the atom. This means that the energy of the emitted photon is $E_\gamma = \Delta E - K$. However, I have seen on some books, as well as my lecture notes that   the energy of the emitted photon is equal to the energy difference between the energy levels of the atom. Now this would mean that $K=0$, so $p_{at}=0$, but now the linear momentum is not preserved. I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what the problem with my resoning is. Thank you very much.

**Note:** The problem says that we can use the classical expression for the kinetic energy of the atom.

Comment: Your two block offset equations appear to be correct. The mass of the atom is "large" (ndeed, we often just treat the atomic core as a "fixed" external potential.) so we can usually neglect the recoil kinetic energy of the atom, but to be exact we should take it into account which is what this question seems to want you to do.

Comment: Since the kinetic energy is quadratic in the velocity, it goes to zero faster than the atomic momentum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When I write the conservation of the energy and the linear momentum I get:
> $$
> p_\gamma + p_{at} = 0
> $$
> becuase the atom is originally at rest, and
> $$
> E_i = E_f + E_\gamma + K
> $$

Yes, this is fine.

> **Note:** The problem says that we can use the classical expression for the kinetic energy of the atom.

OK, that is reasonable.

(Note: I will not work this out in detail, since this is a homework question.)

Starting off, to simplify the notation, since $|p_\gamma|=|p_{at}|$, I will write:
$$
|p_\gamma| = |p_{at}| \equiv p\;,
$$
so we have one equation:
$$
E_i = E_f + cp +\frac{p^2}{2M_{at}}\;.\tag{1}
$$

The above Eq. (1) is a quadradic equation for $p$, you should solve for $p$ and you will see that you can expand in the "small" quantity $\frac{(E_f-E_i)}{Mc^2}$. (Small assuming $|E_f-E_i|<<Mc^2$).

Comment: So, just to be clear, the fact that the energy of the emitted photon is equal to the energy difference between levels is just an approximation, right? @hft

Comment: @Sergio Yes, right.